# Pasar de foreach a while en PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5, while, foreach

Quiero saber como pasar de un `foreach` a `while` en `php`, el siguiente script:

```
<?php
$datos = array('emails.txt');
$destino = 'filtrados.txt';
$fd = fopen($destino, "w");
$emails_unicos = array();
$cuenta = 0;
foreach($datos as $fichero_emails)
{
    $contenido_fichero = file_get_contents($fichero_emails);
    preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $contenido_fichero, $resultado);
    foreach ($resultado[0] as $email)
    {
        if (!in_array($email, $emails_unicos)) {
            $emails_unicos[] = $email;
            echo "<br/>$email";
            fwrite($fd, $email);
            $cuenta++;
        }
    }
}
fclose($fd);
echo "<br />";
echo "Usuarios no registrados $cuenta";
```

Lo que necesito es dejar de usar `foreach` y comenzar a utilizar el `while` pero sin que deje de funcionar el script. Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo.

Lo que hace este script es tomar los datos de un `TXT`, filtrarlo y devolverme todos los datos en limpio.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres pasarlo a `while`, la lectura con `foreach` es más simple y más clara para este caso, a no ser que quieras leer un solo archivo, lo cual no especificas. Tampoco se indica a cuál de los `foreach` te refieres, si a uno de ellos, o a los dos ¿?

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería de hacer el truco, usar un contador manual que interaccione con los elementos del array.

```
while ($cont <= $resultado[0].length())
{
    if (!in_array($resultado[0][$cont], $emails_unicos)) {
        $emails_unicos[] = $resultado[0][$cont];
        echo "<br/>$resultado[0][$cont]";
        fwrite($fd, $resultado[0][$cont]);
        $cuenta++;
    }
    $cont++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apoyo a lo que comenta @A.Cedano pero si de verdad necesitas cambiar esos `foreach` a `while` **por alguna razón en específica** seria de la siguiente forma:

```
$datos = array('emails.txt');
$destino = 'filtrados.txt';
$fd = fopen($destino, "w");
$emails_unicos = array();
$cuenta = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($datos))
{
    $contenido_fichero = file_get_contents($datos[$i]);
    preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $contenido_fichero, $resultado);
    $j = 0;
    $res = $resultado[0];
    while ($j < count($res))
    {
        if (!in_array($res[$j], $datos[$i])) {
            $emails_unicos[] = $res[$j];
            echo "<br/>{$res[$j]}";
            fwrite($fd, $res[$j]);
            $cuenta++;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
fclose($fd);
echo "<br />";
echo "Usuarios no registrados $cuenta";
```

Answer (score 0):

A lo que parece que te refieres es a quitar el primer foreach, dado que tienes un unico elemento en el array  $datos.

Para ello, solo tienes que hacer tres pasos:

1.- el array lo cambias a una cadena de texto:

```
$datos = 'emails.txt';
```

2.- quitas las lineas de foreach sobre data (ahora es solo una cadena).

3.- haces la lectura de la cadena $datos, directamente:

```
 $contenido_fichero = file_get_contents($datos);
```

tu codigo deberia quedar en lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$datos = 'emails.txt';
$destino = 'filtrados.txt';
$fd = fopen($destino, "w");
$emails_unicos = array();
$cuenta = 0;
$contenido_fichero = file_get_contents($fichero_emails);
preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $contenido_fichero, $resultado);
foreach ($resultado[0] as $email) {
    if (!in_array($email, $emails_unicos)) {
        $emails_unicos[] = $email;
         echo "<br/>$email";
         fwrite($fd, $email);
         $cuenta++;
    }
}
fclose($fd);
echo "<br />";
echo "Usuarios no registrados $cuenta";
```